# Stabbing disks in space, or: Galactic alignment

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, grassmannians

I have a collection of $n$ unit-radius disks in $\mathbb{R}^3$, whose centers are
random within a sphere of radius $R>1$, and which are each oriented randomly.
I'd like to find a line $L$ that pierces as many disks as possible:
$L$ "spears" the "hoops," the circle boundaries of the disks.

This question arose thinking about accidental line-of-sight alignment of galaxies.

---

[image: HoopsStabbing400]

          

<sup>$n=100$ disks centers within $R=10$ of origin (red). $L$ pierces $5$ disks.</sup>

---

> ***Q1***. What is growth rate of the expected largest number of piercings by a line $L$, growth with respect to $n$ as $R$ remains fixed?

I expect it grows more slowly than linearly with $n$.
***Update***. @YCor shows in a comment that, in fact, it grows at least linearly.

I'd like to find a max-piercing $L$ without using Plücker coordinates
and intersecting regions on the Grassmannian manifold, which I expect
to be a non-trivial implementation challenge.

> ***Q2***. Is there an "easy" way to find a max-piercing $L$, 
>   even if computationally inefficient?

Comment: You have two parameters, $R,n$. By growth rate, I understand that $R$ is fixed once and for all?

Comment: @YCor. Yes, thanks, I meant growth w.r.t. $n$ with $R$ fixed. Will update.

Comment: (I assume $R$ is fixed). Fix a line $L_0$ passing through the center. The probability that a given circle is pierced by $L_0$ is $p=p(R)>0$ (which can be computed, but I won't). So for $n$ independently chosen circles, the expectation of the number of circles pierced by $L_0$ is $pn$. Hence the sup over all lines (as considered in Q1) is $\ge pn$.

Comment: It's tempting to invert the problem, but I suspect that (along with Pluecker and Grassman) is what you want to avoid.  Anyway, thinking about the space of lines, find what measure (proportion of lines) is intersected by one disk, compute what measure is intersected by two disks, etc.  Now you have the problem of determining the maximum number of overlapping sets of a certain shape in a space of lines. Gerhard "Turn The Problem Inside Out" Paseman, 2017.12.07.

Comment: As a special case:  given a plane with various ellipses of major axis 1, what is a good algorithm for determining the point inside a maximal number of ellipses?

Comment: @MattF. One could construct the "arrangement of ellipses," a planar diagram with cells, partitioning the plane. Then count the depth of each cell. Not an easy computation: Berberich, E., Emeliyanenko, P., Kobel, A., & Sagraloff, M. (2012, June). "Arrangement computation for planar algebraic curves." In *Proceedings of the 2011 International Workshop on Symbolic-Numeric Computation* (pp. 88-98). ACM.

Comment: Is it true that four ellipses have nonempty intersection iff all four triples among them have nonempty intersection?  If so we could reduce the planar problem to a combinatorial one.

Comment: @MattF That's Helly's theorem I think.

Comment: Is it true that 5 ellipses in R^3 are speared by a single line iff all 4-tuples among them are speared by a single line?  If so we could reduce the actual problem to a combinatorial one.

Comment: @Matt No, this is false. It is easier to describe the counterexample if ellipses are replaced by segments in $\mathbb R^2$. All the segments will be contained in a unit radius circle and all will have length slightly less than $2$. If two such segments are parallel, then all diagonals of the circle spear them, except the ones that are almost parallel to them. By taking many such pairs of segments, each rotated slightly, we can achieve that any $n$ of them are speared but all are not. So if the hoops are all in a small vicinity of the origin, we run into trouble.